# Validación de solo números, programa en consola C#

Tags: c#, validación, consola

Estuve intentando la validación para solo ingreso números, pero no me ha resultado a decir verdad

La idea es que solo se puedan ingresar números y de ser el caso contrario volver a pedir el valor.

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese primer valor: ");
int valor1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese segundo valor: ");
int valor2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("El primer valor es: " + valor1);
Console.WriteLine("El segundo valor es: " + valor2);
```

Saludos!!

Comment: saludos Camilo, veo que recién estás iniciando en la programación, te recomiendo darle una lectura a: https://github.com/fredyfx/Curso-Programando-En-One/blob/master/ProgramandoEnOne/Program.cs espero te sea de utilidad, de la misma manera, lleva unos cursos en http://mva.microsoft.com, aqui te dejo más enlaces para que le vayas con todo el power! https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm - https://www.dotnetperls.com/ - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/ - https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Fundamentals-for-Absolute-Beginners - http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/SmartConsoleSetup.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma sería emplear el método [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) para evaluar la conversión de la cadena ingresada por `consola` , si se realizo correctamente retornará `TRUE` , caso contrario `FALSE`.

Obteniendo este valor se puede emplear un  [do{...} while(condición);](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/kefxt662(v=vs.100).aspx) para volver a solicitar una entrada si el valor devuelto por la función [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) es `FALSE`

```
 int valor;
 string n ;
 bool esNumero;
 do
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Ingrese Valor Entero");
   n = Console.ReadLine();
   /* Si es número correcto retornará true y saldrá
      *  del Ciclo*/ 
   esNumero= int.TryParse(n, out valor);
 }
 while (!esNumero);
 Console.WriteLine("El Valor Ingresado es " + n);
```

Answer (score 1):

También puedes hacer algo que aunque es poco ortodoxo es funcional. Puedes realizar la conversión de un String a un Integer dentro de un try y capturar la excepcion resultante. Si en algun momento entra al Catch significa que fue imposible parsear el valor, lo que por supuesto indica que no es un número. Y si nunca entra al catch significa que lo parseó con exito y se trata de un número.

```
String x = <value>;
int y = 0;
try{
    y = int.Parse(x);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.write("No es un numero");
}
console.write(y);
```

Comment: Gabriel, bienvenido a SOes. Si pudieras incluir un ejemplo de lo que indicas en tu respuesta, la publicacion mejoraria mucho. Puedes seguir los lineamientos en el articulo [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

```
int num;

do
{

 num = Validar("Ingresa un numero del 1 al 10");

} while (num < 1 || num > 10)
```

-----------------------> METODO <------------------------------

```
    public static int Validar(string Mensaje)
    {
        int num = 0, v;

        do
        {
            v = 1;

            try
            {
                Console.Write(Mensaje);
                num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                v = 0;

                Console.Write(" (X) Se produjo el siguiente error: {0}", error.Message);
            }


        } while (v == 0);

        return num;
```

### }

en la parte antes del metodo que seria el main, le pides que ingrese un numero (eso lo envias como parametro al metodo para que lo imprima ahí, el ciclo se repetira hasta que el usuario ingrese un dato valido, pero, con el while afuera del metodo, reingresara a pedirle nuevamente el numero hasta que ingrese lo que vos queres en esa condicion, eso para que no tengas que modificar el metodo, solo validarlo afuera, igual lo podes modificar a tu gusto

Comment: es practicamente la misma respuesta de @dev-joel

Comment: Si, esta bien que no tengo tanta relevancia en la plataforma, pero eso hace que mi respuesta sea "la misma"? En mi respuesta el código que planteo da un detalle del error, ya sea por poner un numero muy grande o un carácter (ya se que se puede mejorar), ademas de que, puede aplicar múltiples validaciones con solo llamar al método y enviar el mensaje, ahorrando poner todo ese código en cada validación, ademas de que, como lo puse en el ejemplo, puede aplicar una condición afuera del método para no tener que codificarlo (y como dije, lo puede hacer si lo quiere mejorar, este es el mas simple).

Comment: Y tampoco entiendo porque votaron a mi respuesta con -1 uno de los "super desarroladores" (ademas diciendo que mi respuesta es "prácticamente lo mismo"), agradezco y espero tus respuestas sobre esto, y si con mi explicación, tiene mas sentido el porque de mi código.

Comment: tu respuesta es similar, solo que su implementacion es diferente

Comment: Claro, lo que quiero saber, es si es buena la técnica de validación que implemento, para mejorar como programador y aprender. En mi cabeza lo puede ser ya que aunque implemente mas lineas, permite un poco mas de flexibilidad y detalle de errores (por lo menos en el uso de consola)

Comment: claro que si, el utilizar métodos te permite reutilizar código, y claro que eso es bueno; pero creo que debiste de haber aportado a la respuesta anterior (modificando o comentando) ya que en esencia es lo mismo. Por cierto, no se quien voto en negativo a tu respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder. Yo lo hice así porque te soy sincero, el día que creé esta cuenta, vi justo este post y tenia esta implementan mía, no sabia bien como iba la cosa, y me pareció que el mio al implementarse mediante un método, y usar excepciones, era mas diferente que el original, en estos casos lo ideal hubiese sido mi respuesta sobre el código de Dev Joel no? Ah, vi en tu perfil que manejas MySql, donde me recomiendas aprenderlo para usarlo mas adelante en mis programas de c#? (pago o no)

Comment: Si, por que como dije anteriormente es esencia la misma respuesta, solo que tu implementación le permitiría reutilizar el código de manera eficiente. Y pues no te desanimes, lo importante es estar abierto a opiniones y aprender nuevas cosas. Saludos.