# validacion de campo numerico c#

Tags: c#

tengo una variable

```
int x=  int.Parse(textbox1.text);
```

quiero validar si el valor ingresado es texto envie un mensaje que avise que solo se permiten numeros, pero si pongo

```
if(x==""){...})
```

me da errror porque no se puede convertir de int a string.

Comment: Pregunta duplicada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66668/validaci%C3%B3n-de-solo-n%C3%BAmeros-programa-en-consola-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe un patrón de diseño TryGet, el cual tiene una variación para algunas implementaciones donde quieres preguntar al mismo tiempo que asignas , pero al mismo tiempo quieres manejar excepciones. En este caso es el TryAction (TryParse), la lógica del patrón es así:

```
int resultado = 0;
//  con el out (por sí acaso no lo tienes en mente es un valor de salida que se escribe obligatoriamente al entrar a la función.)

bool esNumerico = Int32.TryParse(textbox1.text, out resultado);

 if (esNumerico)
 { 
    // Si llega hasta aquí, resultado es numérico.
 }
```

Referencia :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

(está en inglés)

Comment: La version espanol: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

puedes validar el campo textbox1 asi

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
        }
    }
```

Esto no te dejara escribir texto solo numeros en el textbox